# Printing types including decorations, template metaprogramming, constexpr, what to use?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++14, constexpr, typeinfo

I have a Trait like this specialized for functions:

```
template <class Ret, class...Args>
struct FunctionTraits<Ret (*)(Args...)> {
   using ReturnType = Ret;

   template <std::size_t>
   using Parameter = std::tuple_element_t<std::tuple<Args...>>;
};
```

Now I want to print the signature of the function without losing the decorators.

For that I implemented a metafunction like this:

```
template <class T>
struct GetTypeInfoString {};
```

It is specialized for every undecorated type, but I also want to print the decorated types. I am using it like this:

```
extern constexpr auto intstr = makeStringLiteral("int");

template <>
struct GetTypeInfoString<int> {
   static constexprt auto & value = intstr;
};
```

Now I already have the basic information, I want to implement a constexpr function:

```
template <class T>
constexpr const char * getTypeInfo() {
    //Something here...
}
```

My goal is that I print the type with the decorations, not just the basic type. Namely: `int const * [][3]`, etc...

Comment: Are you using this to print information to a user or to diagnose template issues?

Comment: I have a table that describes an API and I generate all the metadata. I want to print full signatures and other data. I am implementing a small executable that can query the API for parameters and other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is basically how to get this:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << TypeInfo<const int>::value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << TypeInfo<const int&>::value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << TypeInfo<int&&>::value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << TypeInfo<const volatile int&>::value() << std::endl;
}
```

To produce this:

```
const int
const int&
int&&
const volatile int&
```

In a constexpr manner.

Answer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <class T>
struct TypeInfo;

template<std::size_t N>
struct immutable_string
{
    constexpr immutable_string(const char (&s)[N])
    : _data {}
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i)
            _data[i] = s[i];
    }

    constexpr immutable_string()
    : _data {}
    {
    }

    constexpr char& operator[](std::size_t i) { return _data[i]; }
    constexpr const char& operator[](std::size_t i) const { return _data[i]; }

    using ref = const char (&)[N];

    constexpr ref data() const { return _data; }
    static constexpr std::size_t size() { return N-1; }

    char _data[N];
};

template<std::size_t N>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, immutable_string<N> s)
{
    return os.write(s.data(), s.size());
}

template<std::size_t LN, std::size_t RN>
constexpr auto operator+(immutable_string<LN> l, immutable_string<RN> r)
{
    constexpr std::size_t len = LN + RN - 2;
    immutable_string<len + 1> result;
    std::size_t i = 0;
    for ( ; i < (LN-1) ; ++i)
    {
        result[i] = l[i];
    }
    for (auto j = 0 ; j < (RN-1) ; ++j)
    {
        result[i + j] = r[j];
    }

    return result;
}

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto literal(const char (&s)[N])
{
    return immutable_string<N>(s);
}

template <>
struct TypeInfo<int> {
    static constexpr auto value() { return literal("int"); }
};

template<class T>
struct TypeInfo<const T>
{
    static constexpr auto value() { return literal("const ") + TypeInfo<T>::value(); }
};

template<class T>
struct TypeInfo<volatile T>
{
    static constexpr auto value() { return literal("volatile ") + TypeInfo<T>::value(); }
};

template<class T>
struct TypeInfo<const volatile T>
{
    static constexpr auto value() { return literal("const volatile ") + TypeInfo<T>::value(); }
};

template<class T>
struct TypeInfo<T&>
{
    static constexpr auto value() { return TypeInfo<T>::value() + literal("&"); }
};

template<class T>
struct TypeInfo<T&&>
{
    static constexpr auto value() { return TypeInfo<T>::value() + literal("&&"); }
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << TypeInfo<const int>::value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << TypeInfo<const int&>::value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << TypeInfo<int&&>::value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << TypeInfo<const volatile int&>::value() << std::endl;
}
```

Produces output:

```
const int
const int&
int&&
const volatile int&
```

Update:

A more complete/robust example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct TypeInfo;


template<std::size_t N>
struct immutable_string
{
    constexpr immutable_string(const char (&s)[N])
    : _data {}
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i)
            _data[i] = s[i];
    }

    constexpr immutable_string()
    : _data {}
    {
    }

    constexpr char& operator[](std::size_t i) { return _data[i]; }
    constexpr const char& operator[](std::size_t i) const { return _data[i]; }

    using ref = const char (&)[N];

    constexpr ref data() const { return _data; }
    static constexpr std::size_t size() { return N-1; }

    char _data[N];
};

template<std::size_t N>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, immutable_string<N> s)
{
    return os.write(s.data(), s.size());
}

template<std::size_t LN, std::size_t RN>
constexpr auto operator+(immutable_string<LN> l, immutable_string<RN> r)
{
    constexpr std::size_t len = LN + RN - 2;
    immutable_string<len + 1> result;
    std::size_t i = 0;
    for ( ; i < (LN-1) ; ++i)
    {
        result[i] = l[i];
    }
    for (auto j = 0 ; j < (RN-1) ; ++j)
    {
        result[i + j] = r[j];
    }

    return result;
}

template<std::size_t N>
constexpr auto literal(const char (&s)[N])
{
    return immutable_string<N>(s);
}

template <>
struct TypeInfo<int> {
    static constexpr auto value() { return literal("int"); }
};

template<class T>
struct TypeInfo<const T>
{
    static constexpr auto value() { return TypeInfo<T>::value() + literal(" const"); }
};

template<class T>
struct TypeInfo<volatile T>
{
    static constexpr auto value() { return TypeInfo<T>::value() + literal(" volatile"); }
};

template<class T>
struct TypeInfo<const volatile T>
{
    static constexpr auto value() { return TypeInfo<T>::value() + literal(" const volatile"); }
};

template<class T>
struct TypeInfo<T&>
{
    static constexpr auto value() { return TypeInfo<T>::value() + literal("&"); }
};

template<class T>
struct TypeInfo<T&&>
{
    static constexpr auto value() { return TypeInfo<T>::value() + literal("&&"); }
};

template<class T>
struct TypeInfo<T*>
{
    static constexpr auto value() { return TypeInfo<T>::value() + literal("*"); }
};


int main()
{
    std::cout << TypeInfo<const int>::value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << TypeInfo<const int&>::value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << TypeInfo<int&&>::value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << TypeInfo<const volatile int&>::value() << std::endl;
    std::cout << TypeInfo<const volatile int* const* volatile * const volatile **const *&>::value() << std::endl;
}
```

expected output:

```
int const
int const&
int&&
int const volatile&
int const volatile* const* volatile* const volatile** const*&
```

Comment: Ok, the key point here where I got stuck... static constexpr auto value variable... make it a function and it works!! great idea. Thank you very much. I will accept this reply.

Comment: `immutable_string` aka `std::string_view` or even `std::array`.

Comment: @black constexpr std::array is not mutable until c++17. string_view can't do compile-time concatenation, so unfortunately neither is suitable.

Answer (score 1):

With gnu extension for literal string, you may do

```
template <typename Char, Char...Cs>
struct LString
{
    static constexpr Char value[] = {Cs..., 0};
};

template <typename Char, Char...Cs> constexpr Char LString<Char, Cs...>::value[];

// string literal operator templates are a GNU extension
template <typename Char, Char...Cs>
constexpr LString<Char, Cs...> operator ""_ls()
{
    return {};
}

template <typename Char, Char...Lhs, Char...Rhs>
constexpr LString<Char, Lhs..., Rhs...>
operator + (const LString<Char, Lhs...>&, const LString<Char, Rhs...>&)
{
    return {};
}

template <typename Stream, typename Char, Char...Cs>
Stream& operator << (Stream& s, const LString<Char, Cs...>&ls)
{
   return s << ls.value;
}
```

Then your type and specialization

```
template <typename T> struct TypeInfo;

template <> struct TypeInfo<int> { static constexpr auto value = "int"_ls; };

template<class T> struct TypeInfo<const T>
{
    static constexpr auto value = "const "_ls + TypeInfo<T>::value;
};

// ...
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e386d769dab269b7)

Comment: shame that it didn't make it into the standard. would be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard C++ library function for this, but most compilers do provide some means for demangling signatures.

For gcc, this looks like this.

```
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
constexpr std::string getTypeInfo() {

    int status=0;
    char *t=abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(T).name(), 0, 0, &status);

    std::string s=t;
    free(t);
    return s;
}


template<class C, class T>
void foobar(C c, T t)
{
}

class Z {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << getTypeInfo<int>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << getTypeInfo<Z *[5]>() << std::endl;

    auto *p= &foobar<int, char>;

    std::cout << getTypeInfo<decltype(p)>() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
int
Z* [5]
void (*)(int, char)
```

Comment: Unfotunately the CV qualifiers will be lost with abi

Comment: "getTypeInfo<volatile int \*>()" comes back with "int volatile\*".

Comment: I need a portable solution.

Comment: Then the answer is: there is no portable solution.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes, there is. Not a simple one, though, keeping into account that one needs to get the type of a function with argpack templates.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik see my updated answer for a C++11 solution

Answer (score -2):

Adjusted: took a couple of hours, but anyway

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

template <typename... T> struct type_info;

template <typename... T> struct tail_type_info;

// prints the tail of a <typename...T> type argpack
// Needed to insert commas in the appropriate places
template <typename H, typename... T>
struct tail_type_info<H,T...>
{
  std::ostream & operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    type_info<H>p;
    o << ", ";
    p(o);
    tail_type_info<T...> x;
    return x(o);
  }
};
// if the tail is empty, do nothing
template <>
struct tail_type_info<>
{
  std::ostream & operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    return o;
  }
};

// specialization for the base types
template <> struct type_info<void> {
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    o << "void";
    return o;
  }
};

template <> struct type_info<bool> {
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    o << "bool";
    return o;
  }
};

template <> struct type_info<int8_t> {
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    o << "int8_t";
    return o;
  }
};

template <> struct type_info<uint8_t> {
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    o << "uint8_t";
    return o;
  }
};

template <> struct type_info<int32_t> {
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    o << "int32_t";
    return o;
  }
};

template <> struct type_info<uint32_t> {
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    o << "uint32_t";
    return o;
  }
};

template <> struct type_info<int64_t> {
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    o << "int64_t";
    return o;
  }
};

template <> struct type_info<uint64_t> {
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    o << "uint64_t";
    return o;
  }
};

// TODO fill it in for the rest of the types (char, short, wchar_t)


// compound types (&, *, CV, [N], [])
template <typename T>
struct type_info<T*> {
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    type_info<T> p;
    p(o) << " *";
    return o;
  }
};
template <typename T>
struct type_info<T&> {
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    type_info<T> p;
    p(o) << " &";
    return o;
  }
};
template <typename T>
struct type_info<const T> {
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    type_info<T>p;
    p(o) << " const";
    return o;
  }
};

template <typename T>
struct type_info<volatile T> {
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    type_info<T>p;
    p(o) << " volatile";
    return o;
  }
};

template <typename T, size_t N>
struct type_info<T[N]> {
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    type_info<T>p;
    p(o) << "[" << N << "]";
    return o;
  }
};

template <typename T>
struct type_info<T[]> {
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    type_info<T>p;
    p(o) << "[]";
    return o;
  }
};

// specialization for std::containers
template <typename T>
struct type_info<std::vector<T>> {
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    type_info<T>p;
    o << "std::vector<";
    p(o);
    return o << ">";
  }
};
// TODO define specializations for other containers as necessary

// specialization for std::tuple as an example of variadic template types
template <typename H, typename... T>
struct type_info<std::tuple<H, T...>> {
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    type_info<H>p;
    tail_type_info<T...>tailp;
    o << "std::tuple<";
    p(o);
    tailp(o);
    return o << ">";
  }
};

template <typename H>
struct type_info<std::tuple<H>> {
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    type_info<H>p;
    o << "std::tuple<";
    p(o);
    return o << ">";
  }
};

template <>
struct type_info<std::tuple<>> {
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    o << "std::tuple<";
    return o << ">";
  }
};


// specialization for functions
// function with no args
template <typename R>
struct type_info<R(*)(void)>
{
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    type_info<R>p;
    p(o) << " (*)(void)";
    return o;
  }
};

// function with 1 arg
template <typename R, typename A0>
struct type_info<R(*)(A0)>
{
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    type_info<R>p;
    type_info<A0>a;
    p(o) << " (*)(";
    a(o) << ")";
    return o;
  }
};

// function with multiple args
template <typename R, typename Ah, typename... At>
struct type_info<R(*)(Ah, At...)>
{
  std::ostream& operator()(std::ostream& o) {
    type_info<R>p;
    type_info<Ah>a;
    tail_type_info<At...>a_tail;
    p(o) << " (*)(";
    a(o);
    a_tail(o);
    o << ")";
    return o;
  }
};



template<typename... T> std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& o, type_info<T...>& v) {
  return v(o);
}

template <typename R, typename... A>
std::string FunctionSignatureStr(R(A...)&) {
  std::stringstream dest;
  type_info<R(*)(A...)> funcTrace;
  funcTrace(dest);
  return dest.str();
}

std::vector<long> dummyFunc(std::tuple<const long*[4], volatile bool& > const&) {
  return std::vector<long>();
}

int main() {
  std::cout << FunctionSignatureStr(dummyFunc) << std::endl;

  type_info<std::vector<long>(*)(std::tuple<const long*, volatile bool&> const&)> d;
  std::cout << d << std::endl;
}
```